# dynamic animation with gsap while using bootstrap media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gsap

I'm currently using bootstrap `col-md-4` and `col-xs-12` to make my little web page dynamic to different window width, like the following html:

```
<div class='features'>
  <div class=' blog col-sm-4 col-xs-12'>
    <div class='thumbnail '>
       <img <--!content inside--!>/>
       <h2><--!content inside--!></h2>
       <p><--!content inside--!></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<--!three of them in total--!>
```

To get it a little bit fancy, I try to add some tweenmax, showing `<img>` and `<h2>` at first and making `<img>` disappear, `<p>` appear while my mouse enter. 
The problem is that whenever the three `.thumbnail` get into one block(that is, when window width is wider than 768px), the text would be longer than the frame of its parent.
To make it up, I gave it some conditions to change the height of `.thumbnail`, but none of them can really make the height to change accordingly to window resizing.

here javascript part:

```
//thumbnail//
var height = $('.thumbnail').height()/1.5;
var textheight =($('.thumbnail p').height()+$('.thumbnail h2').height())*2;
var imgheight = $('.thumbnail img').height();

$(".thumbnail").mouseenter(function(){

if(imgheight<textheight){
   height = textheight*1.5;
} else {height = $('.thumbnail').height()/1.5;}

TweenMax.fromTo(this, 0.6,{y:0}, {y:'-=20px', ease: Power4.easeInOut, repeat:1, yoyo:true} );  
$(this).addClass('active-thumbnail-hover').fadeIn(600);

if($('.thumbnail').height()<textheight){
  TweenMax.to($(this), 0.6, {height:textheight});
} else {height = $('.thumbnail img').height()/1.6;}

TweenMax.to($(this).children('h2'), 0.8,{y:-height, ease:Power1.easeInOut,color:'black', background:'none'});

TweenMax.fromTo($(this).children('img'), 0.8, {opacity:1}, {opacity:0, ease: Power1.easeIn});

TweenMax.fromTo($(this).children('p'),0.8,{display:'none'},{display:'block',ease:Power1.easeIn});
});

$(".thumbnail").mouseleave(function(){
 if(imgheight<textheight){
   height = $('.thumbnail').height()*2.5;
   TweenMax.to($(this), 0.6, {height:$('.thumbnail').children('img').height()*1.05});
 } else {height = $('.thumbnail img').height()/1.6;}

TweenMax.to($(this).children('h2'), 0.8,{y:0, ease:Power1.easeInOut, background:'rgba(215,255,210, 0.5)'});

TweenMax.fromTo($(this).children('p'),0.3,{display:'block'}, {display:'none',ease:Power1.easeIn});


TweenMax.fromTo($(this).children('img'), 0.8, {opacity:0}, {opacity:1, ease: Power1.easeIn});

});
```

[here](http://jsbin.com/mebove/edit?output)'s how is it like in my JSBin, sorry it's a bit messy!

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly the part when you say "the text would be longer than the frame of its parent". I had a look at your bin but it seemed ok for what you seem to be trying to achieve, I could be wrong. please explain further.

Comment: hey there! I just checked it out on google chrome, and it seems alright on that browser. <br>I guess it happens only on safari? the `h1` inside `thumbnail` is supposed to move upward, but in safari every first time my mouse enter into `thumbnail`, `h1` goest to the right a little bit before heading up.